# ViewController being held in memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I use the following code to switch between view controllers..(works fine) I have many view controllers too by the way Im not just switching back and forth between 2

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];

MyTableViewVC *detailView = (MyTableViewVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewVC"];

    //pass data through to VC

[self presentViewController:detailView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I see the memory use climbing as I transition between view controllers

So i did some research and realized Im not dismissing the previous view controller. I use the following code `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` before I call `presentViewcontroller:` (I also tried using it after) and it doesn't work. If i use it after nothing happens.. using it before I get the following warning

Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1.... blah blah let me know if you need the rest

Ive also tried to do something like this..

```
[detailView presentViewController:detailView animated:NO completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add identifier to MyTableViewVC in storyboard? or your current viewcontroller include uinavigationcontroller ?

Comment: yes like i said this code works fine.. Im just having problems dismissing the view controller this code is called from

Comment: ***keep in mind*** if you remove the old VC, you will have problem to go to previous VC as you removed those...

Comment: @FahimParkar so i should only be concerned about releasing view controllers that are the highest on the stack?

Comment: @FahimParkar i did.. first chunk of code in my questionNSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];

MyTableViewVC *detailView = (MyTableViewVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewVC"];

    //pass data through to VC

[self presentViewController:detailView animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: that means you are using navigation controller... I believe you have navigation bar.. isnt it?

Comment: @FahimParkar Im using a view controller with a navigation bar placed on top

Comment: that means you are using navigation based view controller... now whenever you go to another vc in view did load write below code and use `[navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 0];`.. try and let me know what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to remove VC from the navigation stack.

```
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];

// [navigationArray removeAllObjects];    // This is just for remove all view controller from navigation stack.
[navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 2];  // You can pass your index here
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
[navigationArray release];
```

**However note,** ***by doing this you will have problem to go to previous VC as you are removng the previous VC from the stack.***

***As you are complaining about memory***, *I would say DOUBLE CHECK code once again and investigate where memory is getting used more. Incase if that object is not needed, release that object so that memory issue would not be there.*

Comment: im not exactly sure how to use this code? am I putting all my view controllers in an array when my app first launches?

Comment: @user3550397 : VC in arrays? Can you post your code that you are using?

Comment: what i meant is i don't understand where to add your code? Im not using navigation view controllers?

Comment: @user3550397 : if not navigation view controller then how you are going from one VC to another VC... show us code how you are going from one VC to another VC...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to back to root view controller, you must use this code.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```